# Creating dynamic spatial view to be displayed on ArcMap and published on ArcGIS Server?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-server, sql-server, arcgis-10.4

I have some datasets: Parks, Park facilities and ParkTrails. These have many-to-many relationship; i.e a park can have multiple facilities and there may be multiple park trails on a single park

I would like to publish this data to ArcGIS Server, and issue queries on it, so that I can get a single result for a single Park. Currently, when mapping  say a pack I get all other parks and facilities as well as Park line and this is somehow confusing and a lot of information to digest at a time when the result is drawn by a text search.

Does anyone know how I can create a spatial view that will generate a unique Object ID field for repeated geometries to enable me publish a park layer with say uniquely identified facilities and park lines?

I am using MSSQL Database server 2012 and ArcGIS 10.4. I would also not want to tamper with my data storage type.

I have tried creating the view from my MSSQL interface but  on bringing it across to ArcCatalog or ArcMap, I keep getting the OID error (ObjectID)and some other errors as shown in the screenshot attached here.

Also at some point, the feature displays on ArcMap to show just  one feature either polygon data or the Line data but when I try to view the attribute table it gives me another error screenshot 2

[image]

[image]

Comment: You need to be ***extremely*** careful when modelling many-to-many with ArcGIS, since it has *no tolerance* for repeating rowid columns. I would recommend you denomalize your data by creating the Cartesian product in a table, then driving your queries through that.

Comment: @Vince I think you should make your comment into an answer

Answer (score 1):

As [commented by @Vince](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/251303/creating-dynamic-spatial-view-to-be-displayed-on-arcmap-and-published-on-arcgis#comment395381_251303):

> You need to be ***extremely*** careful when modelling many-to-many
>   with ArcGIS, since it has *no tolerance* for repeating rowid columns.
>   I would recommend you denormalize your data by creating the Cartesian
>   product in a table, then driving your queries through that.

Answer (score 0):

Try the Row_number function in t-sql to generate an ID in your view.